# Comparing syntax trees modulo alpha conversion

Tags: haskell, syntax, abstract-syntax-tree, np-complete, lambda-calculus

I am working on a compiler/proof checker, and I was wondering, if I had a syntax tree such as this, for example:

```
data Expr
    = Lambdas (Set String) Expr
    | Var String
    | ...
```

if there were a way to check the alpha-equivalence (equivalence modulo renaming) of `Expr`s.  This `Expr`, however, is different from the lambda calculus in that the set of variables in a lambda is commutative -- i.e. the order of parameters does not factor in to the checking.

(For simplicity, however, `Lambda ["x","y"] ...` is distinct from `Lambda ["x"] (Lambda ["y"] ...)`, and in that case the order does matter).

In other words, given two `Exprs`, how can one efficienly find a renaming from one to the other?  This kind of combinatorial problem smells of NP-complete.

Comment: I'm too sleepy to think this through, but your problem sounds like a special case of unification (like in Prolog). Maybe you can look at how that's done?

Comment: Out of curiousity, if you use the unbound package, and define `Lambdas [Name Expr] Expr` (instead of using a Set), does the `aeq` function do the Right Thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commutativity of the parameters does hint at an exponential comparision, true.

But I suspect you can normalize the parameter lists so you only have to compare them in single order.  Then a tree compare with renaming would be essentially linear in the size of the trees.

What I suggest doing is that for each parameter list, visit the subtree in (in-order, postorder, doesn't matter as long as you are consistent) and sort the parameter by the index of the order in which the visit first encounter a parameter use.   So if you have

```
  lambda(a,b):  .... b .....  a  ... b ....
```

you'd sort the parameter list as:

```
  lambda(b,a)
```

because you encounter b first, then a second, and the additional encounter of b doesn't matter.    Compare the trees with the normalized parameters list.

Life gets messier if you insist the the operators in a lambda clause can be commutative.  My guess is that you can still normalize it.

Comment: You need to split the variables into those that occur in the body and those that don't.  The ones that don't can be ignored.

Comment: I'm not sure you can ignore the ones that don't occur.  A function with 3 arguments, one of which is not used, is not the same as a function with 4 arguments, 2 of which are not used, even if they compute the same result semantically.    I think all you do with the unused ones is put them in any order at the end of the parameter list.

Comment: I didn't mean totally ignore them, as you say you still have to compare cardinality of the non-occurring sets.

Answer (score 4):

We can appeal to Daan Leijen's [HMF](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=132621) for a few ideas. (He dealing with binders for 'foralls', which also come across as commutative.

In particular, he rebinds the variables in the occurrence order in the body.

Then comparison of terms involves skolemizing both the same way and comparing the results.

We can do better than that by replacing that skolemization pass with a [locally nameless representation](http://www.chargueraud.org/research/2009/ln/main.pdf).

```
data Bound t a = Bound {-# UNPACK #-} !Int t | Unbound a

instance Functor (Bound t) where ...
instance Bifunctor Bound where ...

data Expr a
  = Lambdas {-# UNPACK #-} !Int (Expr (Bound () a))
  | Var a
```

So now occurrences of Bound under a lambda are the variables bound directly by the lambda, along with any type information you want to put in the occurence, here I just used ().

Now closed terms are polymorphic in 'a' and, if you sort the elements of the lambda by their use site (and can ensure that you always canonicalize the lambda by removing unused terms) alpha equivalent terms compare simply with (==), and if you need open terms you can work with Expr String or some other representation.

A more anal retentive version of the signature for Expr and Bound would use an existential type and a type level natural to identify the number of variables being bound, and use 'Fin' in the Bound constructor, but since you already have to maintain the invariant that you bind no more variables than the # occurring in the lambda and that the type information agrees across all of `Var (Bound n _)` with the same `n`, its not too much of a burden to maintain another.

Update: You can use my [`bound`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound) package to do an improved version of this in a fully self-contained way!